# read the specific data from the JSON file and load on tableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
    i have text file in project which i put the JSON data now i read the data  properly but problem occur when specific field was read program was crash fatal error andy one help me my code 

      let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("days", ofType:"json")
       let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path!)
  //  println(jsonData)
             var jsonResult: NSDictionary =   NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    //   println(jsonResult)
          for var i = 0 ; i < jsonResult .valueForKey("MONDAY")!.count ; i++ {
           arrDic!.addObject((jsonResult.valueForKey("MONDAY") as!  NSArray).objectAtIndex(i))
       println( arrDic!.addObject((jsonResult.valueForKey("MONDAY") as! NSArray).objectAtIndex(i))

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ahmad") as! TableViewCellahmad

    cell.labelTxt.text = arrDic[indexPath.row].valueForKey("TITLE") as?  String
    cell.detailLblTxt.text = arrDic[indexPath.row].valueForKey("DETAILS") as? String
  return cell
```

Thats the code read the data properly my JSON format of the data but when i want to fetch the MONDAY than crash the program error is fatal error

```
{
"MONDAY": [
           {
           "TITLE": "TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT",
           "SPEAKER": "JASON SHAPIRO",
           "TIME": "9:00 AM",
           "ROOM": "MATISSE",
           "DETAILS": "EXPLORE THE TOPICS AND TOOLS RELATED TO TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT."
           },
           {
           "TITLE": "JAVA TOOLS",
           "SPEAKER": "JIM WHITE",
           "TIME": "9:00 AM",
           "ROOM": "ROTHKO",
           "DETAILS": "DISCUSS THE LATEST SET OF TOOLS USED TO HELP EASE SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT."
           }
           ],
"TUESDAY": [
            {
            "TITLE": "MONGODB",
            "SPEAKER": "DAVINMICKELSON",
            "TIME": "1: 00PM",
            "ROOM": "PICASSO",
            "DETAILS": "LEARNABOUT\"NOSQL\"DATABASES."
            },
            {
            "TITLE": "DEBUGGINGWITHXCODE",
            "SPEAKER": "JASONSHAPIRO",
            "TIME": "1: 00PM",
            "ROOM": "VANGOGH",
            "DETAILS": "EXPLOREDIFFERENTPATTERNSFORDEBUGGINGYOURIOSAPPS."
            }
            ],
"WEDNESDAY": [
              {
              "TITLE": "SCRUM MASTER",
              "SPEAKER": "DAVIN MICKELSON",
              "TIME": "1:00 PM",
              "ROOM": "MATISSE",
              "DETAILS": "LEARN THE ROLES AND RESPONSIBILITIES OF A SCRUM MASTER"
              },
              {
              "TITLE": "DESIGN PATTERNS",
              "SPEAKER": "JIM WHITE",
              "TIME": "1:00 PM",
              "ROOM": "ROTHKO",
              "DETAILS": "APPLY BEST PRACTICES AND SOUND ARCHITECTURES TO SOFTWARE DESIGN."
              }
              ]
```

}
       Thats the JSON format i want only fetch the TITLE and DETAILs